# Как работает canvas при отрисовке отдельных фигур?

Tags: javascript, html5, canvas

Здравствуйте.

Отрисовываю на canvas упорядоченные фигурки. Каждую отдельно взятую фигурку можно перемещать по полотну (используя DnD). 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Во время перемещение фигурки перерисовывается полностью весь холст (насколько я понимаю), что не есть эффективно для производительности.
Если я создам дополнительный элемент canvas и во время анимации буду рисовать в нем отдельно взятую фигуру, а в предыдущем полотне (где все фигурки), воспользуюсь clearRect на определённую область, где размещалась ранее определенная фигурка до перемещения и по окончанию анимации перерисовать весь основной хослт.

Уточните, пожалуйста, верно ли я мыслю в данном направление или как работает canvas изнутри, если я на холсте изменяю хотя бы один пиксель (он реально перерисует весь холст или только один пиксель)?

Спасибо!

Comment: Большинство ответов на свой вопрос я нашел [тут](https://habrahabr.ru/post/119772/)

Comment: Можете ответить на свой собственный вопрос, это не запрещено правилами и даже поощряется. Помимо увеличения репутации на сайте (полезно для создания следующих вопросов) можно рассчитывать на некоторую дискуссию в комментариях, если вдруг читающие заметят грубые ошибки.

Answer (score 0):

по поводу производительности - для такого малого числа фигур эффективнее будет как раз очищать весь холст (достаточно быстрая операция), и заново все перерисовывать учитывая `DnD`.

Канвас это битмап изображение, с отснотительно низкоуровневым API, рендеринг на котором ещё и аппаратно ускоряется.

Так что лишние телодвижения по типу создать отдельный канвас элемент и рисовать там только одну фигуру - на мой взгляд тут ни к чему.